# How to read BIOS Flash Memory?

Tags: drivers, bios, flash-memory

In the "Intel® Desktop Board DQ77MK Technical Product Specification", there is a section called "BIOS Flash Memory Organization". The content of this section is

> The Serial Peripheral Interface Flash Memory (SPI Flash) includes a 96 Mbit
>   (12288 KB) flash memory device.

How to read this memory on Linux (debian)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [flashrom](https://www.flashrom.org/Flashrom), it can read the contents of most motherboard flash chips. (It can also write them but that's beyond the scope of your question.)

Unfortunately in your case the BIOS and ME are [locked](https://www.flashrom.org/Supported_hardware#mainboards_note106), so flashrom can't read the chip, and I don't think anything else can (that's the whole point of the BIOS lock). You'll need external tools to read the flash memory: Intel's own tool (used to upgrade the BIOS), or an external reader.

Comment: This answers my questions. I am trying to accept it, but it says I can't accept an answer in 2 minutes. I couldn't get the tool to work on my machine, though. I wonder if there is something as simple as `cat /dev/mtd`.

Comment: Right, I hadn't noticed that the DQ77MK is locked. Flash chips like this aren't mapped in MTD-style, there is no simple way of getting at their contents...